# Prob. 6 (d), Chap. 3, in Baby Rudin, 3rd ed: What about the convergence of this series for $\vert z \vert >1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n \colon= {1 \over {1+z^n}} $ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, where $z$ is a given complex number.

Then what about the convergence of the series $\sum a_n$?

My effort:

When $\vert z \vert \leq 1$, we have 
$$\vert a_n \vert = {1 \over \vert 1+z^n \vert } \geq {1 \over {1 + \vert z \vert^n } } \geq {1 \over 2 }$$ for all $n$ so that 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \neq 0,$$ 
and the series fails to converge.

What if $\vert z \vert > 1$?

In this case, for all $n$, we have 
$$\vert a_n  \vert =  {1 \over \vert 1 + z^n \vert } \leq {1 \over {\vert z \vert^n - 1}}. $$

What next?

(How) can we compare this series with a geometric series?

Comment: Using the fact that "every monotone bounded sequence converges", we can see that for a fixed $z$ with $|z|>1$,${a_n}$ converges to $0$.So, we can say that the function converges to the zero function when $|z|>1$.

Comment: Yes, but convergence of the sequence $a_n$ to zero is only necessary and not sufficient for convergence of the series $\sum a_n$.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but AD's approach is not the fastest.

As you already noted,

$$|a_n|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^n-1}$$

But

$$|z|>1\implies |z|^n-1\geq |z|^n-|z|^{n-1}$$

Hence

$$|a_n|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^n-|z|^{n-1}}=\frac{|z|}{|z|-1}\frac{1}{|z|^n}$$

The terms on the right-hand side are the terms of a convergent geometric series with ratio $1/|z|$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that 
$$\frac{1}{1+z^n} \sim \frac{1}{z^n} = \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n$$
that is they are similar, what we have to do is to find out how similar they are.

To start with, we have 
$$\frac{1}{1+z^n} = \frac{1}{z^n}\frac{1}{1/z^n +1}=\frac{1}{z^n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z^n}}$$
and for fixed $z$, with $|z|>1$ 
$$\left|1+\frac{1}{z^n}\right|\geq 1- \left|\frac{1}{z^n}\right|$$
is close to 1. In fact for $|z|>r>1$ there is an $n$ such that  $1- \left|\frac{1}{z^n}\right|>\frac{1}{2}$.

I believe you can complete the proof from here.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I'm unable to pick up from where you've left; so I'd really appreciate if you could take time filling in all the details as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: we have that $|a_n|>{1\over 2}$ for all $n$.So,compare it with the constant sequence $(1/2,1/2,...)$.Then, we conclude that, the series diverges.

Comment: @SrinivasK No, that is only true for $z$ with $|z|\leq1$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Please, can you tell me what part is unclear?

Comment: @AD.I'm unable to pick the "similarity" argument in Srinivas K's proof. If $\vert z \vert > 1$, the series $\sum \left(1 + \frac{1}{z^n} \right)$ diverges, but how can we know from this fact about the behavior of our original series?

Comment: This is what we have: 1. The terms in the sum is $(1/z)^n \cdot(1/(1+1/z^n))$.  2. A series with terms like $(1/z)^n$ converges whenever $|z|>1$ (it is the reciprocal of a geometric series). 3. From 1. and 2. it suffices to prove that $(1+1/z^n)$ is bounded from below.